# Airflow Sensor Operator - github PR

Tags: python, github, airflow

Would it be possible to config an Airflow sensor (thinking maybe the @task.sensor decorator sensor) that could listen for a PR to be merged in a Github repo and trigger the DAG run based on that?  Ideally outside of using Github Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow sensors are just python classes, they should have a method `poke` which return True when the thing you want to wait happens.

To achieve what you want to do, you can use the library `PyGithub`, to get the state of the PR and return True when it is merged (and fail when it is closed).

[Here](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/doc/examples/PullRequest.rst) is the link to the doc, and the [source code](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/master/github/PullRequest.py) if there is something not documented.

Comment: Adding to that: the [GithubSensor](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/github/modules/githubsensor) abstracts some of the logic needed around this.

Comment: for further info on the github sensor...https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-github/stable/_api/airflow/providers/github/sensors/github/index.html

Comment: @TJaniF might you have an example code to accomplish this?  The documentation on the airlfow operator is a little light.